# 0% Alpha layer within a collision movie clip in Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, layer, collision

I'm currently making a game and the visuals are on one layer in my 'back' movie clip, and my blocks for the collisions in the layer below.

Is there any way to hide the collisions layer, so it doesn't show up in the SWF but the player still collides with it? If I just put alpha = 0 or visible = false in the actions on the layer, it hides all of my background and my character is on nothing.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to hide the collisions layer, so it doesn't show up
>   in the SWF but the player still colides with it?

To be honest, layers don't really matter a whole lot when it comes to code. It just helps you visually sort out content and organize matter. That having been said, let's say that your instance name for the collision blocks is "collision_blocks". All you have to do is type:

```
collision_blocks.visible=false;
```

instead of

```
visible=false;
```

I hope that is making sense. Instead of setting the whole layer invisible, you code the particular content you wish as invisible.

Comment: Drake, he removed the signature. According to the official community rules, you don't add a signature to your questions or answers, as your title card serves as your sig. (Hint: To see what was edited, click "edited .... ago")

Comment: I'll add a caveat to this answer...layers matter very much if you created a guide or mask that way. That aside, what you said is right. You hide objects, not layers.

Comment: Thanks for informing me @JasonMc92! I didn't know we weren't supposed to use signatures. And true, layers can be helpful for those kind of situations